# Does QuickBooks have any kind of audit log?

Tags: quickbooks-online

QuickBooks allows users to change posted periods. How can I tell if a user does this?

I actually don't need an audit log, but just the ability to see recently added/edited data that has a transaction date that's over a month in the past.

In a meeting today it was suggested that we may need to refresh data for all our users going back as far as a year on a regular basis. This would be pretty time consuming, and I think unnecessary when the majority of the data isn't changing. But I need to find out how can I see if data (such as an expense) has been added to a prior period so I know when to pull it again.

Is there a way to query for data (in any object or report) based not on the date of the transaction, but based on the date it was entered/edited?

I'm asking this in regard to using the QBO api, however if you know how to find this information from the web portal that may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

QuickBooks has a `ChangeDataCapture` endpoint which is specifically for *exactly* the purpose you are describing. It's documented here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/changedatacapture

The TLDR summary is this:

> The change data capture (cdc) operation returns a list of objects that have changed since a specified time.

e.g. You can continually query this endpoint, and you'll only get back the data that has actually *changed* since the last time you hit the endpoint.